# Amazon ElasticBeanstalk: configure environment variable with newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add environment variable with newlines to my application using ElasticBeanstalk such as RSA private key. I have the following form for this purpose: [image]

and AWS CLI as well.

Comment: What happens when you add that environment variable?

Comment: @AndreyMyatlyuk The application restarts. I solved this with providing path in an environment variable to a file with newlines.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want to add a key file to my build, as we build from git, and keys in version control can be a security hazard, so I used this workaround instead:

```
# From your shell: Base64 encode the RSA private key file
# -w 0 disables wrapping, we don't want new lines
base64 -w 0 id_rsa
```

Base64 encoded data doesn't have newlines, so you can use the output directly as an ElasticBeanstalk environment variable. You can then use this variable inside your application like so:

```
# From the shell
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode - > .ssh/id_rsa
# Or just decode it with some other programming language of your choice
```

This way, you don't have to include the file that you're referencing into your build, but you can contain the key completely in the environment variable.

Comment: How did you get Elastic Beanstalk to add `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`? It's too long so I get `Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Parameter 'EnvironmentVariables' default value ...`